# Running rails rake commands I get this deprecation warning

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: railtie_name is deprecated and has no effect. (called from require at /Users/bm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:64)
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
    ...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method Hs::Application#task called at /Users/bm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@hs/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize_tasks'
```

Just created a new rails application (rails 3.0.7).

I see the above message each time I run a rake command.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have the newest version of Rake installed, which is not compatible with Rails 3.0.7.

Stick this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rake', '~> 0.8.7'
```

and run `bundle update`

After that call your rake tasks prepending: `bundle exec`

Comment: thanks, but now its saying: You have already activated rake 0.9.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.8.7. Consider using bundle exec.  get I fix this?

Comment: As mentioned by kain, you should now run your commands with bundle exec. for example 'bundle exec rake db:migrate'

Comment: The alternative would be to upgrade rails to 3.0.9, rake 0.9.2 will work fine with it.